# Swift : How can I use delete and share button in Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode6

I'm using commitEditingStyle for delete. I added share button in a cell. Now I'm just using sharing button in cell. I want to use both of this in cell. Should I use custom delete button like my "Share" button ? What can I do for this ?

My code is here :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source

            var object: PFObject =  self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
            object.delete()

            self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()
            self.fetchAllObjects()
            tableView.reloadData()
            //tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
    {

        var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Share") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

            let object: PFObject = self.noteObjects[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
            let firstActivityItem = object["title"] as! String
            let secondActivityItem = object["text"] as! String

            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

            self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }

        shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        return [shareAction]

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

return multi `UITableViewRowAction` in `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
{
    var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Share") { 
        (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        let object: PFObject = self.noteObjects[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
        let firstActivityItem = object["title"] as! String
        let secondActivityItem = object["text"] as! String

        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

        self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") {
        (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        //...
    }

    return [deleteAction, shareAction]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved this issue. I used custom cell too for the delete action and that worked.

Here is the final code to delete and share action in cell :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
{

    var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Share") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        let object: PFObject = self.noteObjects[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
        let firstActivityItem = object["title"] as! String
        let secondActivityItem = object["text"] as! String

        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

        self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Delete") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        var object: PFObject =  self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
        object.delete()

        self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()
        self.fetchAllObjects()
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return [deleteAction,shareAction]

}
```